# Is $(a,b) → (2a+3b,3a+4b)$ bijective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f : \mathbb{Z×Z}  → \mathbb{Z×Z}$ with $(a,b)  → (2a+3b,3a+4b)$. Is $f$ bijective?

Comment: **Hint.** What is $f(3v-4u, 3u-2v)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider the determinant of the corresponding matrix.

Or use Gaussian elimination to solve
$$
2a+3b = u,  \quad 3a+4b=v
$$
for $a,b$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$ will give you $a-c=b-d=0$ and from $f(a,b)=(m,n)$ you will be able to write $a$ and $b$ as linear combinations of $m$ and $n$, so the solutions are integers (because the determinant of the matrix is -1). This will prove the injectivity and surjectivity.